# React Native Unbundling and Inline Requires

Tags: react-native

I tried implementing the unbundling and inline requires to my project.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#unbundling-inline-requires

It works on simulation but when I release the project on iOs or create an apk for android errors occurred:

`TransformError:  /Users/<user_name>/codebase/<projectfoldername>/<project_name>/clients/mobile/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo.ios.js: /Users/<user_name>/codebase/projectfoldername/<project_name>/clients/mobile/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo.ios.js: NodePath has been removed so is read-only. (This is an error on an internal node. Probably an internal error)`

and also this:

`error: File /Users/<user_name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project_name>-fggebbxvaywbawbbcoypijwnkwjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/therion_mobile/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/<project_name>.app/main.jsbundle does not exist.`

Then I noticed that the component AccessibilityInfo is in the waiting module but the instruction from the link I pasted above said that only the loaded modules will be put on the moduleNames.

I tried to put the modules that are waiting to the moduleNames.js it resulted to a success in release but the speed of the mobile app did not improve. This occurred on both iOs and Android platforms.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or if there is something I need to know to successfully implement unbundling and inline requires on my react native project? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to `metro.config.js` and make sure that `index.js` and the `metro.config.js` files are at the same level and change `ROOT_FOLDER` to this:

```
const ROOT_FOLDER = resolve(__dirname, '.');
```

Just **one** dot to tell metro they are in the same level.